# In what folder is JAVA_HOME being called

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm setting up Flutter for the first time and came across this error. I was told to find the java_home variable somewhere in a java folder but running automatic scans and manually searching has come up empty-handed. Do I have to download something external or is it just very hard to find? Any help is appreciated.

> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JAVA_HOME

Comment: Please, mention the operating system your are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

You need to set the environment variable JAVA_HOME in your machine